# Iframe map inside accordion

Tags: html

my iframe code is not rendering inside accordion panel in html,
i used the **iframe embedded map** inside the accordion panel,it is not rendering properly.
Can anybody give me a solution for this? mine is html css website.

Comment: What do you mean by "not rendering properly"? do you have a screenshot or anything?

Comment: it is rendering for half of the portion and remaining part is grey.

Comment: Could you post a screenshot?

Comment: I removed that frame and had put one screenshot. Thanks for your response. I will let you know if any pbm comes.